# JAX-RS and JAXB entity causes bad request with space before xml preamble

Tags: jaxb, jersey, weblogic, jax-rs, moxy

I'm testing my JAX-RS service using the RESTClient FireFox extension. Sometimes I mistakenly paste in a space before the xml preamble. This causes a 400 Bad Request when I do my PUT. Is there anyway to get Jersey/JAXB to ignore the white space?

WebLogic 12c with Moxy 2.4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML parser that [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) or any other [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation uses is going to thrown an exception if there is a space before the XML declaration.  If you are passing the XML as a `String` then you could call trim on it  first.

Comment: Not really the answer I want but it is the answer I need. Maybe I'll take a look at a filter.